# Detection system with other software are playing music

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

How to judge whether the system has other software are playing music ios？ Thankyou！！！

Comment: Sorry... What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

To see if other audio is playing you can check `kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying` property. [From Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

```
UInt32 propertySize, audioIsAlreadyPlaying;

propertySize = sizeof(UInt32);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &propertySize, &audioIsAlreadyPlaying);
```

[How do I detect if other apps are playing background audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152549/how-do-i-detect-if-other-apps-are-playing-background-audio)